# Book reference for heat kernels on Riemannian geometry

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I am looking for an introduction to heat kernel on Riemannian manifolds and bundles over them. Also, I want to learn some basic about Spectral Geometry.

I found on the internet *Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds* by Alexander Grigoryan, but unfortunately I don’t have access to this book.
I’m also considering to read *The Laplacian on a Riemannian Manifold: An Introduction to Analysis on Manifolds* by Steven Rosenberg.

Therefore, I appreciate any book or other sources (e.g. lecture note, survey).

My background knowledge is Introduction to Topological/Smooth/Riemannian Manifolds by John Lee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access *Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds by Alexander Grigoryan*. You can do so by purchasing it from the AMS website.

Anyways,

Here are some books that discuss the mentioned topics and i think you may find interest in:

> (1): [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628)

> (2): [Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/heat-kernels-and-spectral-theory/39DC7EE2A5DCCE9DEF581D2F52A73E1F)

> (3): [Lectures on spectral geometry](https://impa.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/15_CBM_85_07.pdf)

> (4): [Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=AMSIP/47)

Hope i helped!

P.S: All of those are graduate/ research level textbooks/ notes.